# How to get a full list of loopback4 models to evaluate custom decorator metadata at boot time?

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I'm currently migrating a `loopback3` application to `loopback4`. I've annotated the properties in my `loopback4` models with a custom typescript decorator with some metadata.

How can I get a full list of models and evaluate their metadata at boot time?

I did some experiments with `LifeCycleObserver`, but did not find a way how to get notified when all models are ready nor get a list of them.

Here is an simplified example of the metadata i want to process. Please note: `@propertyAcl` is a custom decorator.

```js
export class Model1 extends AuditMixin(SoftdeleteMixin(AbstractEntity)) {

  // ...

  @property()
  @propertyAcl({
    'role1': Permission.READ_WRITE,
    'role2': Permission.READONLY,
  })
  myproperty?: string;

  // ...
}
```

I need to configure the external library `accesscontrol` with the metadata at boot time. The idea is to create property based acls per model.

Comment: According to my understanding, you want to use a custom decorator on each model's property, and then take all the relevant metadata out in a class. ？？

Comment: Yes, something like this. As far i can see, there is no `ModelBooter` which can be asked for all existing `loopback4` models.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get a full list of models and evaluate their metadata at boot time?

#### Overview

Using [@loopback/metadata](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/tree/master/packages/metadata) to create a `Decorator` and define / get the metadata via `MetadataInspector`.

1. Create a `DecoratorFactory` "A"
2. Create a `Context` "B"
3. Overide the `mergeWithInherited` function in "A", and in this function we store (define) the metadata of the property that you annotated at design time to "B"
4. Create a `Decorator` "C" via "A"
5. Annotate any properties you want with "C"
6. Get the metadata in "B" at runtime

#### Step 1 2 3 4

```js
// 1
class A extends PropertyDecoratorFactory<object> {
    constructor(key: string, spec: object, options?: DecoratorOptions | undefined) {
        super(key, spec, options);
    }
    // 3
    mergeWithInherited(inheritedMetadata: MetadataMap<object>, target: Object, propertyName?: string, descriptorOrIndex?: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any> | number): any {
        // define metadata to "B"
        MetadataInspector.DesignTimeReflector.defineMetadata(`${target.constructor.name}.${propertyName}`, this.spec, B);
    }
}

// 2
export const B = new Context("B.context");

// 4
export function C(spec: object): PropertyDecorator {
    return A.createDecorator<object>(
        'C.decorator',
        spec,
    );
}
```

#### Step 5

```js
class ModelFoo extends Model {

    @property({
        type: 'string'
    })
    p1?: string;

    @C({ metadata: "this is ModelFoo" })
    @property({
        type: 'string'
    })
    p2?: string;

}

class ModelBar extends Model {

    @property({
        type: 'string'
    })
    p1?: string;

    @C({ metadata: "this is ModelBar" })
    @property({
        type: 'string'
    })
    p2?: string;

}
```

#### Step 6

```js
function Test() {
    // get all metadata keys in "B"
    let keys: string[] = MetadataInspector.DesignTimeReflector.getMetadataKeys(B);

    // output >>>> [ 'ModelFoo.p2', 'ModelBar.p2' ]
    console.log(keys);

    // get metadata with 'ModelFoo.p2' in "B"
    let metadata = MetadataInspector.DesignTimeReflector.getMetadata(keys[0], B);

    // output >>>> { metadata: 'this is ModelFoo' }
    console.log(metadata);

    // do somthing...
}
```